# What maps port described as Teredo?

Tags: ubuntu, upnp

I've looked at upnp in router and i saw something unknown.
InternalPort:54172
ExternalPort:54172
Protocol:UDP
Description:Teredo
I'm using ubuntu and i don't know which application maps this port.

```
sudo netstat -tlnpu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5298            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1713/telepathy-salu
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1019/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5276            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1640/skype      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49603           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4102/transmission
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4102/transmission
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1201/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::5298                 :::*                    LISTEN      1713/telepathy-salu
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1019/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::49603                :::*                    LISTEN      4102/transmission
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59421           0.0.0.0:*                           939/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1075/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5276            0.0.0.0:*                           1640/skype      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           939/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49603           0.0.0.0:*                           4102/transmission
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51942         0.0.0.0:*                           1640/skype      
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                939/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::47483                :::*                                939/avahi-daemon: r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Teredo Tunneling Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) is a network protocol that lets you route IPv6 packets across an IPv4 network. This lets a PC with an IPv6 address to talk to a server running IPv6, even if some of the routers in between the two only understand IPv4.

It's unlikely to be an individual application using this, it's something the network stack of the OS is likely to supply when it's needed without the application really knowing that it's being used.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ubuntu use command `sudo netstat -tlnpu` to see the list of applications currently bound to some port. See the *Local address* column, find there the *5147* or *54172* and see from *PID/Program name* column, what is the program using that port.

Or try `sudo netstat -tlnpu | grep 5417` for avoiding the eye-strain caused by the potentially long list ... :-)

Comment: but i see nothing there with this port

Comment: Can you copypaste the output of that sudo netstat -tlnpu?

Comment: i've put it to the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a Teredo client called Miredo in Ubuntu but it doesn't use uPnP. Microsoft Windows Vista and later will create this port-mapping.